# Will SQL charset wildcard query work on Oracle database?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run the following query

```
SELECT * FROM GEEKYBRAINS.admin_emp where ename like '[sm]%';
```

It results in an empty set.

The `admin_emp` table has the following data though.

[image]

I am running this on Oracle database. Will the charset wildcard search work with Oracle database ?

Comment: It'll work, you just need to remove the braces.

Comment: I want to select all enames starting with s and m which is why I have given them inside the braces. I saw a tutorial on w3schools [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_wildcard_charlist&ss=-1) where they are using this syntax and it is running on the "Try it yourself" simulator. I have tried removing the braces but no luck ! Without braces I think it will search for the names that start with "sm" which is not my intension.

Comment: Just leave the w3fools site and never go back.

Comment: That's not a "*SQL*" wildcard. The `LIKE` operator in "SQL" (the query language) only knows two wildcards `%` and `_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `regexp_like`:

```
select ename
from admin_emp
where regexp_like(ename,'(^[sm])');
```

Example SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee053/5).

Comment: Alternative: `where ename like 's%' or ename like 'm%'`